# Setting defaultRowPrefetch as a JVM property

Tags: java, jdbc, fetch

I'm trying to set oracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch as a JVM property by passing the parameter to java command using -Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch but didn't succeed. The value is still 10 (default) after checking on Oracle database.
Is there a mean to change this value without modifying the source code of application?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this IBM Support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-defaultrowprefetch-oracle-jdbc-driver):

> You cannot set `defaultRowPrefetch` as a JVM property. [...] You can only use this property by loading it into a `Properties` object in the code and then calling `getConnection` with the `Properties` object.

The Oracle JDBC documentation concurs ...